# How can I trouble shoot a debian hotspot?

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wifi-hotspot

Creating a hotspot is much easier than I remember from the last time I did it, but I'm not sure how to trouble shoot this failure.

I was able to create an AP using `nm-connection-editor`. This worked great for connecting my Android phone, Arch laptop, and an older Mac. However, another android phone and a windows laptop are both unable to connect. The error is simply "Unable to connect." I've also been able to connect all the devices if I make the AP open, which is fine for testing but I don't want to run it like that indefinitely. I was also able to connect both phones prior to upgrading debian from 9 -> 10.

I don't see anything of interest in the debian logs. What are some good steps to narrow down the possible cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error is simply "Unable to connect."

To get debug info on Android, I use [MatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pluscubed.matlog&hl=fr&gl=US) (available in FDroid too)

On the Debian side, Hotspots can be handled with `nmcli`:

```
nmcli connection up Hotspot
```

You *may* get more info with

```
nmcli -t device show
```

See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmcli.1.html)

I've been able to toggle the Hotspot On/Off in one click in Gnome, I can dig in my notes if you want, but the starting points were [Argos](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos) and [this script](https://github.com/bozmen/gnome-hotspot-toggle)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the debug and see what else I can learn. I also tried the one click gnome option and it's the same problem. I suspect it's a wpa_supplicant config problem but I'll see.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112280/issue-with-some-devices-not-connecting-to-raspberry-pi-set-up-as-ap) on the pi exchange that is strikingly similar to my issue.

Though not absolute, it seems that `wpa_supplicant` doesn't support an authentication method for `wpa2` but advertises `wpa` and `wpa2` nonetheless. Old clients that only use `wpa` won't notice a difference, and some clients that will try both will succeed with `wpa` but others will try `wpa2` have it fail and then give up.

I solved this issue by installing `hostapd`.